# Which combination of os.FileMode's corresponds to `a` in fopen, with respect to the permissions on the created file?

Tags: go, io

Consider the following short program in Golang, which simply attempts to write a file.

```
package main

import "io/ioutil"
import "os"

func main() {
    ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/FooBar", []byte("Hello World"), os.ModeAppend)
}
```

After running this program, I get a file with the following permissions.

```
---------- 1 merlin sudo 5 Oct 12 15:02 /tmp/FooBar
```

The permissions are essentially unuseable.

If I run the equivalent C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE* foo = fopen("/tmp/BarFoo", "a");
    fprintf(foo, "Hello World");
    fclose(foo);
}
```

Then I get a file that looks like this, which is much more desirable.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 merlin sudo 11 Oct 12 15:10 /tmp/BarFoo
```

**What is the correct combination of flags in the `Golang` program to produce a file with the same permissions as the C program?**

I have looked at the [FileMode documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode) but did not see any good candidates.

Comment: `w+` doesn’t append. Try `os.ModeAppend | 0644`, anyway.

Comment: @minitech, I had intended to append, but the focus is on the permissions of the file after the operation. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @minitech, That works! I will accept that answer, although I do wonder whether one must always explicitly specify the permissions to have anything reasonable given that this is not needed in most other languages.

Comment: I think many of them do, but with 0666 as reasonable defaults, since their permissions and modes are separate.

Comment: Yeah that behavior is a bit surprising. I'm probably mixing up the method in `ioutil` with another one but I'm fairly certain I've written plenty of files in Go without ever considering this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `FileMode` includes permission bits for newly-created files, you’ll need to provide those:

```
ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/FooBar", []byte("Hello World"), os.ModeAppend | 0644)
```

Comment: Does this actually work? Just curious because the docs for `ioutil.WriteFile` explicitly say it truncates the file.

Comment: @Endophage, I am not trying to match behavior exactly with the `C` program, just to get the permissions on the resulting file correct.

Comment: @merlin2011 don't take offense but I wasn't asking for your benefit :-P I'm actually curious if this will append because I would use it. I guess I'll just hack up a tiny test program to see.